# Javascript for loop goes over loop constraint, possible misunderstanding of closure

Tags: javascript

Basically I have some event listeners and their handling function defined as follows:

```
<div id="postTextBlock"/>
<div id="postImageBlock"/>
<div id="postQuoteBlock"/>
<div id="postLinkBlock"/>

document.getElementById('postTextBlock').addEventListener('click', function() { showPostType(postTextBlock) }, false);
document.getElementById('postImageBlock').addEventListener('click', function() { showPostType(postImageBlock) }, false);
document.getElementById('postQuoteBlock').addEventListener('click', function() { showPostType(postQuoteBlock) }, false);
document.getElementById('postLinkBlock').addEventListener('click', function() { showPostType(postLInkBlock) }, false);

var showPostType = (function () {
    var postTypes = new Array('postTextBlock', 'postImageBlock', 'postQuoteBlock', 'postLinkBlock')

    return function(type) {
        for (var i = 0; i < postTypes.length; i++) {
            (function(index) { alert(document.getElementById(postTypes[index])) })(i)
        }
    }
})()
```

When I run this I will get 5 alerts.  One for each of the postTypes defined in my array and a final null for what I'm guessing is `postTypes[5]`.  Why is it executing the code with `i = 5` when I have set the for loop to terminate when `i = 5` (`postTypes.length` = 4).

Edit:
I added the html that it references as well as the full array values.  Hopefully this clears some stuff up about the code not working.

Comment: Are you sure that the length is `4`? With a very basic loop it works: http://jsfiddle.net/tbGYV/ , so I guess the error is in  `postTypes.length` and/or it cannot find the element.

Comment: have you overwritten your array constructor?

Comment: Felix Kling: Yes, its 4.  I've checked it in the debugger multiple times.  I don't know why.  One of the first things I did when I first encountered the error is use the basic loop that you posted.

Comment: helle: what do you mean "overwritten array constructor".  Are you asking if I created my own array object of the same name as the default javascript Array class?  If so, then the answer is no.

Comment: It looks like you understand, or at least know how to use closures, but in the example you provided, you definitely don't need a closure for the inner function (the `function(index)` one).

Comment: possible duplicate of [Javascript closure inside loops - simple practical example](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/750486/javascript-closure-inside-loops-simple-practical-example)

Answer (score 0):

You know your code sample doesn't work?  I took a stab at what it's --supposed-- to do.

http://jsfiddle.net/8xxQE/1/

```
document.getElementById('postTextBlock').addEventListener('click', function() {
    showPostType('postTextBlock'); //Argument does nothing
}, false);
document.getElementById('postImageBlock').addEventListener('click', function() {
    showPostType('postImageBlock'); //Argument does nothing
}, false);
```

The arguments passed above were not included, based on the function code they did nothing anyways.

```
var showPostType = (function() {
    var postTypes = new Array('postTextBlock', 'postImageBlock')

    return function(/*type argument removed isn't referenced*/) {
        var l = postTypes.length;
        for (; l--;) {
            (function(index) {
                console.log(index, postTypes[index]);
                alert(document.getElementById(postTypes[index]))
            })(l);
        }
    }
})()
```

I added some trickery as just an example of a better way to write a for loop.  Your closure works fine, I think you are doing something else to cause this code to not work as expected.  Why would this error run 4 times, there's only two items in the array.  My example ran exactly twice every time I clicked a div, as you can see on JSFiddle.

Comment: The code I posted up was somewhat annotated, I guess it wasn't very clear what was left out.  I've added the rest of the code so things will be more clear.

Comment: For a while, I thought I saw 5 alerts when I ran your code, too, but then it turns out I was counting wrong.

Answer (score 0):

The div's id is "postLInkBlock", but you're searching for "postLinkBlock". That's the null.

Comment: That was just a typo in the example code.  I am getting 5 discrete alerts.